# Buttons in Bootstrap (3) are getting rendered without any default padding when using React

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently learning React and I'm trying to render some buttons in my app. However, when they're rendered in the page they all show all grouped together and without the default margin.

[Image of buttons rendered without default margin using React](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucqN4.png)

I'm unable to reproduce this problem when I render a static HTML version:

[Image of buttons rendered with default margin using HTML only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDzb6.png)

I'm not sure at all how to troubleshoot this and I would like to be able to use Bootstrap in React without having to add my own CSS.

In case it helps, the exact same thing happened some time ago when I tried to append the same buttons using jQuery before starting to learn React. I was unable to fix it back then as well.

**React code**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Container extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <div className="panel panel-default question">
                    <Title/>
                    <Body/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    };
};

class Title extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="panel-heading">
                <h3 className="panel-title">Panel Title</h3>
            </div>
        );
    };
};

class Body extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="panel-body">
            <p className="panel-question">Question Content</p>
          <textarea className="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
          <div >
            <OptionList/>
          </div>
        </div>
        );
    };
};

class OptionList extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="button-container text-center">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Option 1</button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Option 2</button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Option 3</button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Option 4</button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Option 5</button>
            </div>
        );
    };
};

export default Container;
```

**HTML Only**:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="panel panel-default question">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Panel Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p class="panel-question">Question Content</p>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
          <div >
            <div class="button-container text-center" id="button-container">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Option 1</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Option 2</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Option 3</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Option 4</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Option 5</button>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Does anyone know how to overcome this issue? Will this happen with other React elements as well? Thanks for the help and any feedback you may have!

Edit:

I'm not using any custom CSS but the app is using the default CSS from create-react-app:

**App.css**

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  height: 80px;
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #222;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.App-title {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.App-intro {
  font-size: large;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

**index.css**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: The code look ok. Can you share the css? Or atleast, the complete class defination where you are adding the padding

Comment: Looks like react automatically removing spaces between the elements. In your html version, if you remove the space between button like `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Option 1</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Option 2</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Option 3</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Option 4</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Option 5</button>` that also won't give any gap between buttons. Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/128456/

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai that's interesting... any idea how to avoid React "removing" those spaces?

Comment: @ivp I'm not using a custom CSS file... However I am using the default create-react-app CSS files. I'm using the same CDN links to include bootstrap in both the React app and the static HTML one...

Comment: You can add `{' '}` to preserve space.

Comment: @AndreasLOrozco I am not sure how to resolve that. I think you have to change your html by adding `{` `}`. Read more information here https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4134